# How to debug navigationcontroller.tintColor not changing?

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason I can't figure out why I'm not able to change the `tintColor` of my navigation bar buttons in my app and I don't know how to figure out why. Can you recommend how I can debug this issue?

I am adding this to the viewDidLoad of my view controller:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .green
```

However, nothing changes and the back button and Aa bar button stay the default grey color.

The navigation + status bars are translucent and sit on top of the background color of the `viewcontroller` through out the app.

I am able to change the `barbutton` to .green in a test app where I do the exact same (add it to ViewDidLoad of a vc, make sure that the barbutton images assets are set to Template so they'll take on the color I set). But for whatever reason, that same thing won't change in my app prototype.

Are there are any common reasons for this that I might not know of?

Added: the bar button was added via storyboard only.

And here is the code attempt to change its color via the viewDidLoad of 1 viewcontroller:

```
Class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .green
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Please paste your code rather than screenshots. And how you added the bar buttons? `UIBarButtonItem` directly or with custom view? can you show us the code?

Comment: In main storyboard, this controller is embed with UINavigation controller? If yes then click on Navigation Controller and click on attribute inspector there is check of Show navigation Bar click on that. then your navigation bar is visible because in image your navigation bar is not visible.

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal I have add what you asked. The bar button was added via storyboard only, no code. I don't want the navigation bar visible - I have made it translucent in the code and want it that way. I only added that in case it affected the tintColors for the bar button items on a transparent navigation bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the global `appearance()` proxy, then you can't do it in your view controller.

If you want to change the `tintColor` in `viewDidLoad` of your view controller then you have to set it on your controller's `navigationController` instance directly:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .green
```

To use the `appearance()` proxy, and set a global `tintColor` for navigation bars, you'll have to do it before your navigation controller is initialized.

For example, it will work if you do it in your app delegate's `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .green
    return true
}
```

See the `UIAppearance` documentation for details of why this is:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance

"iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back."

Comment: Ahh yes. This solved it for me. Thank you for the explaining when to set appearance() for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Navigation Bar color**

To change the background color of the navigation bar, use the below code

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .green
```

Change `.green` with your desired color.

**Navigation Bar Text Color**

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.green]
```

Change `.green` with your desired color.

Comment: I dont need to change background color as navigation bar is transparent through my app. There is also no title or text in the navigation bar as the bar buttons are image assets. I added the navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.green] with a test title in the view controller, but that line also doesn't change the title color to green, just like my line of code (UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .green
) won't change the tintColor of the barButtons. I'm looking for ways to debug why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hex:"YourColorcode")
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
                                                        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-Medium", size:19.0)]

UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
                                                     NSFontAttributeName: "YourFontName"], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. I dont need to change the barTintColor because its clear or title because there is none. I just need to change the .tintColor but I can't get it to work. I am adding UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .green directly to my viewDidLoad but it does not work and I need ways to figure out why this might be